# Custom AccountPicker for Google accounts with user photos

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-account

I want to implement OAuth login with Google. What is the best way to get all user's Google accounts with images?

I can get a simple Google account list with `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent` but I want a list with user photos like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI874.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting Android 4.0 (API level 14) or higher you might want to use Contacts Provider.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile